# What's up with this question:

Tags: discussion

***[Do sounds from different musical instrument merge together into one wave?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/69508/do-sounds-from-different-musical-instrument-merge-together-into-one-wave)***

One day with 19 upvotes and 27 on the answer? Based on our normal numbers, that seems wildly out of proportion.

Not to mention that there have been questions about duplicate accounts from this particular user, and any number of questions from them that all deal with one subject: See [***Love Sandoval***](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/48605/love-sandoval)  and several other similar accounts. Also note @Richard 's comment on this question: ***See also How do multiple sound waves interact physically to create music?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> One day with 19 upvotes and 27 on the answer? Based on our normal numbers, that seems wildly out of proportion.

That's because it has become a [Hot Network Question](https://stackexchange.com/questions), potentially showing in the sidebar on every stack exchange site:

[image]

Such questions always attract many more views, and generally attract more votes as a result.

As Andrew T. points out in a comment below, There is a post (that seems to have been updated recently) about how 'hotness' is calculated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page).

> there have been questions about duplicate accounts from this particular user

yes...

https://music.stackexchange.com/users/48605/love-sandoval
https://music.stackexchange.com/users/48345/adam-lovia
[https://music.stackexchange.com/users/49153/daniella-zättarlund](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/49153/daniella-z%C3%A4ttarlund)
https://music.stackexchange.com/users/48343/hiluluk-adde

These people seem to have similar interests and writing styles. I've been assuming they are 'close friends'... but the questions they've asked seem reasonable (if a little repetitive!).

Comment: _These people seem to have similar interests and writing styles_ Also similar names, and they happen to join at close points in time to one another. This is the latest in a series of accounts like this - seem to take on part of the previous name and build a new one most of the time. It's not just these two... I upvoted your answer over there - I don't mean to begrudge anybody any points - it's mostly this 'chain account(s)' I'm wondering about.

Comment: I missed daniella-zättarlund.. - there was also one with what I think was a japanese name - but **always** new users with the same writing style and identical interests. There have been at least half a dozen like that. Some of them I flagged.  It just does not smell right to me...

Comment: I just realized: How did it become "a hot network question" to begin with - lots of upvotes? If so, then this answer isn't answer. (Admittedly I do not know the criteria for "a hot network question").

Comment: @Stinkfoot yes, I thought there were a few more as well - if you recall any more let's add them to the list here! I tried having a look for if there was any public information about HNQs are calculated, but all I found was [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions), which provides clues but I couldn't spot a definitive answer.

Comment: Each time you suspect user accounts are sock puppets, flag them with a comment to let us know. We do then check and take action

Comment: @DoktorMayhem can we consider these 3 as under investigation already?

Comment: And... what would happen if they did seem to be the same person? Their questions themselves seem just about OK.

Comment: When we identify sock puppets we either merge onto one, or delete all the puppets just leaving a single one

Comment: There can be exceptional actions depending on what they did, and suspensions are not unknown :-)

Comment: @topomorto actually, the HNQ formula is documented on [How do the “arbitrary hotness points” work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756)

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks - I've incorporated in the answer.